# I am trying to install docker. Whenever i run sudo apt-get update, i get this error:

Tags: linux

```
Hit:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                           
Get:2 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease [3,316 B]                              
Hit:3 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch InRelease
Ign:2 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease
Hit:4 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease
Hit:5 https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any any InRelease
Fetched 3,316 B in 4s (774 B/s)

Reading package lists... Done

W: GPG error: http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4773BD5E130D1D45
W: The repository 'http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (stable/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker-ce.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target Packages (stable/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker-ce.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target Packages (stable/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker-ce.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target Packages (stable/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker-ce.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming or docker.  Please try something like https://askubuntu.com , [unix.se] or [su].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, the error is unrelated to Docker! Nevertheless, to still help you around this issue: You need to add the Spotify repository GPG key to yor apt keys. You may do so by issuing the following command in a shell:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 4773BD5E130D1D45
```

You can find this information in the [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/spotify). Please note that on the [Spotify forums](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Linux/W-GPG-error-http-repository-spotify-com-stable-InRelease), someone reported that he needed to add another key to make it work:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A87FF9DF48BF1C90
```

I did not test any of them personally (using Arch linux), but I used Ubuntu some years ago, and am familiar with this kind of issue.

PS: If you try which one actually worked for you, let me know so that I can update the answer. Thanks!

Comment: still getting these warnings:

W: Target Packages (stable/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker-ce.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1

W: Target Packages (stable/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker-ce.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1

Comment: yes, this is yet another issue. it seems you configured the docker packages twice, once in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker-ce.list as well as /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list. remove one of them, leave whichever you prefer.

Comment: The second GPG key worked correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much. My issue is solved now.